# Como recoger la url de un template y pasarla a otro template DJANGO

Tags: django

Hola tengo una duda y es que al filtrar por fecha saco unos parametros de date min y date max donde filtro
[image: parametros]

La cuestion es que quiero pasar esos datos a otro template pero que no apunta a necesidades sino a pdf.html como podría pasarlo?

Adjunto codigo:

```
     <div class="input-group date">
                <b class="b-form">DESDE:</b><input type="date" class="form-control" id="publishDateMin" name="date_min" value="{{format}}">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i>
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group date">
                <b class="b-form">HASTA:  </b>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="publishDateMax" name="date_max" value="{{format2}}">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i>
                </span>
            </div>

def BootstrapFilterView(request):
date_min = request.GET.get('date_min')
date_max = request.GET.get('date_max')
date_max = fecha + timedelta(days=1)
format2 = date_max.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


context = {
    'queryset': qs,
    'format': format,
    'format2': format2
}

return render(request, "app/necesidades.html", context)
```

Dónde quiero pasarlo es otro template llamado listpdf.html

```
 <b><u><p class='title'>NECESIDADES {{AQUI QUIERO DATE MIN}} {{AQUI QUIERO DATEMAX}}</p></u></b>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que falta que detalles mas que es eso de listpdf.html, si llegas desde otra url, que view usa, etc.

Suponiendo que en necesidades.html tienes una url que te lleva al view que renderiza listpdf.html entonces desde el view de necesidades harías esto:

```
def BootstrapFilterView(request):
    date_min = request.GET.get('date_min', None)
    date_max = request.GET.get('date_max', None)
    date_max = fecha + timedelta(days=1)
    format_min = date_min.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if date_min else None
    format_max = date_max.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if date_max else None

    if format_min and format_max:
        url_listapdf = reverse('minombreurl_listapdf') + '?min=' + format_min + '&max=' + format_max
    elif format_min and not format_max:
        url_listapdf = reverse('minombreurl_listapdf') + '?min=' + format_min
    elif not format_min and format_max:
        url_listapdf = reverse('minombreurl_listapdf') + '?max=' + format_max
    else:
        url_listapdf = reverse('minombreurl_listapdf')

    context = {
        'queryset': qs,
        'format_min': format_min,
        'format_max': format_max,
        'url_listapdf': url_listapdf,
    }

    return render(request, "app/necesidades.html", context)
```

Dentro de necesidades.html donde tendras la url hacia tu listapdf con los query si los tiene

```
<a href="{{ url_listapdf }}">Link a listapdf</a>
```

Ya en tu view de listapdf

```
def ListaPdfView(request):
    date_min = request.GET.get('date_min', None)
    date_max = request.GET.get('date_max', None)
    format_min = date_min.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if date_min else None
    format_max = date_max.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if date_max else None

    context = {
        'format_min': format_min,
        'format_max': format_max,
    }

    return render(request, "app/listpdf.html", context)
```

Y en tu listpdf.html

```
 <b><u><p class='title'>NECESIDADES {{ format_min }} {{ format_max }}</p></u></b>
```

Comment: El problema es que al pasar al listpdf se me queda la fecha guardada por defecto del dia actual i siguiente y yo si quiero poner otra diferente no se guarda en la url